# SQL Server query related to grouping and counting for inventory analysis

Tags: sql, sql-server, inventory-management

My table is concerned with inventory items, stocking levels and required numbers. An example is given below:

```
Part     Sub Part         Pieces Required        Pieces In Stock

Barbie    Legs                 2                      1000
Barbie    Arms                 2                      5000
Barbie    Head                 1                       20
Barbie    Torso                1                     40000
Dora      Legs                 2                      1000
Dora      Arms                 2                      5000
Dora      Head                 1                       0
Dora     Torso                 1                     40000
```

I want my end result to look like:

```
Part         No: of dolls that can be built

Barbie           20
Dora              0
```

So the logic is we need a minimum number of each part to make a complete doll. If even one of the required parts is not in stock, then no doll can be made. The complexity comes when we need 2 of certain parts and only 1 of other parts. 
How do I achieve this using SQL Server?

Thank you in advance for your help and time.

Comment: `select part, MIN(PiecesInStock) As PiecesInStock
from tblName
group by part`

Comment: I think you need to divide the stockCount by the requiredCount for a buildableCount and get the `MIN()` of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT part, MIN([Pieces In Stock]/[Pieces Required]) AS PossibleCompleteDolls
FROM tblName 
WHERE [Pieces Required] <> 0
GROUP BY part;
```

The WHERE clause here is just to prevent division by zero.

Answer (score 1):

First add a column of how many can be build with each piece

```
 SELECT *, CAST([Pieces In Stock]/[Pieces Required] as INTEGER) AS canmake
 FROM TABLE
```

Then group that by the part and take the min

```
 SELECT Part, min(canmake) as [No: of dolls that can be built]
 FROM (
   SELECT *, CAST([Pieces In Stock]/[Pieces Required] as INTEGER) AS canmake
   FROM TABLE
   WHERE [Pieces Required] != 0
 ) T
 GROUP BY Part
```